# Nattable dialogs localization

Tags: eclipse, localization, rcp, nattable

I want to add new localization for nattable dialogs "Customize styles" (called from popup menu -> "Edit styles) and "Column Chooser" (from "Choose columns").
But org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable have only 2 localization Bundles: "en" and "de". 
Is there is any way to add my own bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new localization property files via fragments. There should be various articles in the internet regarding that topic.

Comment: But this bundles and class that uses them are in the jar file, so I can't add properties files there

Comment: No, create a new fragment project with the NatTable bundle as host plug-in. The properties files need to be located in the same package as in the NatTable jar. The OSGi runtime will do the rest. Or are you using NatTable in a plain swt project?

Comment: Yes, i'm using NatTable in a plain swt project

Comment: Then your only chance is to modify the jar file by putting the properties files in the right folders

Comment: Although, in a plain swt project everything is in one classloader. So creating a jar with the properties files in the right position should work